# What is the tense/verb phrase of: I was not used to their accents

Tags: phrases, verbs, tenses

Really struggling to understand tenses that do not have an action & I have looked up everything I think it is but it does not appear to qualify/be correct. I have been staring at this for hours.

I would really appreciate any help now as its 1am and i have been googling all verbs & tenses for about 4 hours+ :/

Comment: Do you understand how "I was not accustomed to their accents" parses?

Comment: related: 1. [The difference between “I used to” and “I'm used to”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/220242/the-difference-between-i-used-to-and-im-used-to) 2. [How did “used” get its meaning?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/67229/how-did-used-get-its-meaning)

Comment: Dictionaries can help to clear up any confusion, look up the expression “used to” [**adjective**
1. made familiar with; accustomed to: *I am used to hitchhiking*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/used--to)

Comment: Sorry @Robusto, I dont even know what parses means, just looked it up.

Comment: Thanks @Mari-Lou, I will definately do that; so is it an auxiliary verb? Is that the answer?

Comment: The "verb" is to be , i.e. *was*, "used to" is an idiom, an adjective. "I AM / WAS used to coffee"; "He IS / WAS used to tea" It's like saying: "I am accustomed to coffee", same thing. Just because the adjective ends with -ed it doesn't mean it is a verb. There are many adjectives that end in -ed: *bored*, *depressed*, *excited*, *thrilled*, *endangered*, etc.

Answer (score 4):

The sentence in the title

> *I was not used to their accents.*

contains one verb -- *was* -- and it's past tense.

The phrase *used to* in that sentence is **not** the past tense idiom. 
It's another idiom, pronounced the same way /'yustə/, but with a different meaning. ***Be used to*** means the same as *be accustomed to*.
**This** *used to* idiom is a predicate adjective and requires an auxiliary *be* verb (that's the *was*)

- *She is **used to** taking the 9:12 bus.* = She is accustomed to taking the 9:12 bus.
- *I will never get **used to** their accents.*

The other *used to* idiom doesn't use an auxiliary verb; it ***is*** an auxiliary verb, with a special sense.

- *I **used to** live in Chicago.* = I lived in Chicago at some past time (but I don't live there now).

So, if you see a *be* verb in front of *used to*, it's the "accustomed to" sense, not the past sense.

Comment: So it is an accustomed verb, not auxiliary verb? Just to clarify as I go to study up on accustomed verbs which |I have never heard of :/ Thank you so much I was completely lost.

Comment: Ok, theres no such thing as a accustomed verb, so its an auxiliary verb or a modal auxiliary? I do not appear to understand these at all and am currently looking them up; auxiliary is still not making sense to me sadly. I realise the sentance was using 'used to, as in accustomed to or no longer familiar with but I still dont get the auxiliary very well clearly :/ Thank you again.