# "Used to" in reported speech

Tags: grammar, past-tense, speech

- She said I used to eat too much.
- She said I was used to eat too much.

Which one is correct? If both are correct, do they mean the same thing?

Comment: Can you say what they are supposed to mean?

Comment: [There are two idioms](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/281224/15299), they don't mean the same thing, and they have different grammar. But they're both pronounced /yustə/ or /yustu/, and not /yuzd tu/.

Comment: Questions that are primarily about correctness are probably better handled over at [ell.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is used correctly, the second one is not.

You can say "I used to *verb*" to indicate it is something you usually did in the past.

You cannot say "I was used to *verb*". You would have to write "I was used to *noun*.". For example, "She said I was used to eating too much". Here you are indicating that you were accustomed to something happening. It sounds worse than the first option for this specific case in which the thing you are accustomed to is you doing something. It is more common to use it for things external to you, for example: "I was used to his presence so it did not bother me."

Comment: Thanks @Luismi98! Your answer is very sound and clear!