# Is the use of "be used to" correct in the following context?

Tags: grammar

I would like to have an explanation on the use of the structure *Be used to*. I've always thought that It refers to habitual actions in the present. But a native speaker marked this sentence of mine as a mistake, "It is a pillow developed for sleeping on a plane for those who are used to travelling frequently" and put instead, "..for those who are use to travelling..."

I've never seen this structure *Be use to* (without the *d* at the end of "use") before and it does not sound correct to me at all. But I surprisingly found it used very frequently on the internet. So I just don't understand.

Comment: They were wrong. You were correct when you wrote "used". Here's a link[link](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/used_1)

Comment: See [kiamlaluno's earlier answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/30137/16052). Many (most?) pronounce *used to* and *use to* in the same way, so when written there is a temptation to hypercorrect. The same phenomenon occurs with *[supposed to](http://english.stackexchange.com/qs/8129)*. Another common error is *[could of](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/usage/could-of-or-could-have)* for *could've*. Related: *[What's the negation of “I used to be”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/8816)* and *[What is the question form of “used to do”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/16480/)*

Comment: There are [**two** different "used to" idioms](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/314973/15299), both pronounced /justu/. One is a predicate adjective and means 'accustomed to' (_I'm used to this car now_). It requires an auxiliary _be_ verb. The other is the complex past habitual construction.

Answer (score 1):

Your usage of "be used to" was correct. But it's not exclusively used to "refers to habitual actions in the present." You can use "be used to" in any tense. For example:

> - When we lived in Bangkok, we **were** used to hot weather.
> - I **have been** used to snakes for a long time.
> - You **will** soon be used to living alone.